# Hibernate allocationsize default value is not 50

Tags: hibernate, jpa, oracle11g

I am using Hibernate @SequenceGenerator in my application. While trying to insert new entity in DB using the application, the ID of the new persisted entity is same as the sequence current value, not the current value of sequence multiplied by 50. As The default value of allocationsize is 50. Do you have any idea why this happened. Thanks in advance.

```
@javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_NAME", sequenceName="SEQ_NAME"")
@Table(name="TABLE_NAME")
public class entity{
    @Column(name="ID")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_NAME"")
    int id;
```

Comment: A SEQUENCE is defined in the database ... what is it set to there? and who created the SEQUENCE?

Comment: yes, the sequence exists in the DB, and I can check its value using this SQL line "SELECT seq_name.nextval FROM DAUL;". The problem is the persisted entity id value is same as the current sequence value.

Comment: which doesn't answer the questions ...

Comment: The DB Admins created the sequences, not me. If I understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sequence was seemingly created by a DBA, and not by your `JPA` provider. Consequently there is absolutely zero point in specifying the `allocationSize` to `JPA` (since it is only for use in schema/sequence creation). If you want a particular `allocationSize` you need to tell your DBA to set this up when creating the `SEQUENCE` (normally via something like `INCREMENT BY`).

Comment: After some investigation and search I found this warring in the console while the application is running. openjpa.Runtime: Warn: Unable to cache sequence values for sequence "SEQ_NAME". Your application does not have permission to run an ALTER SEQUENCE command. Ensure that it has the appropriate permission to run an ALTER SEQUENCE command. Which means that the JPA will disable sequence caching, In case of  the user executing this command doesn't have permissions to execute the Alter command.

Comment: Also I found a solution to this issue by enabling this property. <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="DisableAlterSeqenceIncrementBy=true"/>, but still the persisted entity ID value same as the DB sequence current value.

Comment: As I said, your DBA set the SEQUENCE to one value and not the one you wanted. The JPA provider tried to change it to your setting,but you haven't given it permission. So the solution is talk to your DBA!!

Comment: And please tell everybody WHY an OPENJPA property makes any difference at all when you say you're using HIBERNATE?!!!!

Comment: Exactly OpenJPA property shouldn't have any effect while I am using Hibernate. Seems that Increment the DB sequence to mach the allocationSize will fix this issue. Make sense, So I will accept this answer. Thank you

Comment: But I am wondering why I got this OpenJPA warring in the console? Although I am using the Hibernate implementation